# Event for dynamically generated checkbox and texbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

My english is not good but i need help please!!!

I am dynamically adding rows to a table, add textbox and checkbox.

I want to insert into each textbox value as marked or not each checkbox

(If checked = true -> value = '1' else -> value = '')

```
function agregar(){
var fila = $('<tr></tr>');
var columna = $('<td></td>');
var input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({name: 'idiomas_usu[]', id:'list1'});
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({name: 'dos', class:'cb2', id:'cb2' });
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({name: 'idiomas_usu[]', id:'list2'});
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({name: 'dos', class:'cb2', id:'cb3' });
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({name: 'idiomas_usu[]', id:'list3'});
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({name: 'dos', class:'cb2', id:'cb4' });
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="text" />').attr({name: 'idiomas_usu[]', id:'list4'});
columna.append(input);
input = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr({name: 'dos', class:'cb2', id:'cb5' });
columna.append(input);
fila.append(columna);
$('#tab_logic').append(fila);
 }

function updateBox(event){
var textbox = document.getElementById("list1");
        var values = [];

        if(document.getElementById('cb2').checked) {
    values.push("1");
}

 textbox.value = values.join(" ");
 }

 $('#boton').click(agregar);
 $('#tab_logic').on('click', '.cb2', updateBox);
```

I succeeded in doing only with the first textbox and checkbox generated, as I can do with the rest ??

Here's the code running: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rko41z88/1/)

Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle. See if it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: Include two more inputs and works perfect. Another question; as it could include a delete button row that code?  
Thank you!